# Logging not written in IIS

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, iis-5

I am using Flat File Listener.

It does login in "c:\temp\log.txt" when running in Visual studio's web development server.

**But nothing is written when hosting it in my local IIS on the same machine.**

I have already granted anonymous authentication in IIS.

I am using Visual studio 2008,IIS 5.1 and EntLib 4.1.

Let me know what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure sounds like permission issues.  If you are running your application out of process then the process will be aspnet_wp.exe and the account it runs under will be MACHINENAME\ASPNET.

You should verify that the ASPNET account has write permission to the c:\temp folder.  If not, then grant the ASPNET account write access.

If that doesn't work and you still need to troubleshoot, download [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from sysinternals to see if there are any ACCESS DENIED messages.  Although a bit old and using the legacy tool Filemon, (which Process Monitor replaces), [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890960) goes through the troubleshooting steps and what to look for.

Comment: Thanks Tuzo ! Problem solved.As you said ,it was permission issue.

Comment: Dude - it's almost always a permissions thing.

Answer (score 0):

Does the worker process have access to write in c:\temp?  It's been awhile since I've worked with IIS 5 so I'm not sure which account the worker process runs under, but you should check that it has access to write to c:\temp.

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the properties dialog for the c:\temp folder, and ensure that the account IIS is running under has write access to the folder (and its children).  This is just standard Windows security.

To check which account IIS is using, there should be a setting in the IIS management console.  The default account starts with "IUSR_".

You can always try giving write access to "Everyone" for c:\temp to see if that fixes the problem, before you try to narrow it down to a specific account.  If granting "Everyone" write access doesn't work, its not a permissions issue...